# Create Distributed Portgroup with VLAN id in VMware vSphere SOAP api

Tags: soap, vmware, vsphere

I'm trying to create a distributed port group with a vlan ID in a VDS in VMware vSphere using the SOAP api. I can get it to create the port group, but it never assigns the vlan id. Here is the request I am sending as the spec to the CreateDVPortGroup_Task method (in the Managed Object Browser):

```
<spec>
   <name>Test</name>
   <numPorts>10</numPorts>
   <defaultPortConfig type="VMwareDVSPortSetting">
     <vlan>
       <inherited>false</inherited>
       <vlanId>123</vlanId>
     </vlan>
   </defaultPortConfig>
   <type>earlyBinding</type>
   <autoExpand>false</autoExpand>
</spec>
```

This creates a portgroup, but does not set the vlanId.

I see that it expects a DVPortSetting for the defaultPortConfig, but vsphere retains it as a VMwareDVSPortSetting object.

I've seen a few examples around the web doing it through [other means](http://blog.jgriffiths.org/?p=342), but I just need the format of the SOAP message. Could someone provide me with a sample soap request that would create a distributed port group with a vlan id?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured It out by looking through the implementation of [vijava](http://sourceforge.net/p/vijava/code/HEAD/tree/). Instead of using the type attribute, you have to use 'xsi:type'. What I was looking for was:

```
<spec xsi:type="DVPortgroupConfigSpec">
   <name>Test</name>
   <numPorts>10</numPorts>
   <defaultPortConfig xsi:type="VMwareDVSPortSetting">
     <vlan xsi:type="VmwareDistributedVirtualSwitchVlanIdSpec">
       <inherited>false</inherited>
       <vlanId>123</vlanId>
     </vlan>
   </defaultPortConfig>
   <type>earlyBinding</type>
   <autoExpand>false</autoExpand>
</spec>
```

Frustratingly simple!